# Python: Is there a place when I can put default imports for all my modules?

Tags: python

Is there a place when I can put default imports for all my modules?

Comment: You don't want default imports. You want imports to be explicit, so that you know what is being imported. Otherwise you are going to end up with namespace conflicts that are hard to find.

Comment: @Lennart: not really, if all of his imports are `import module` rather than `from module import names`. But it's still better to use explicit imports -- the main reason being this helps splitting different parts of program. I'm trying to elaborate in my answer below.

Comment: @LennartRegebro What do You think about ilya n's answer and what's name of the concept he presents (I'd like to find more questions on this topic)?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: The concepts he present are mainly the same as mine. "Don't do it". The explicit default imports with the * import are a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just create a separate module and import it into yours.

Example:

```
# my_imports.py
'''Here go all of my imports'''
import sys
import functools
from contextlib import contextmanager  # This is a long name, no chance to confuse it.
....


# something1.py
'''One of my project files.'''
from my_imports import * 
....

# something2.py
'''Another project file.'''
from my_imports import * 
....
```

Note that according to standard guidelines, **`from module import *` should be avoided**. If you're managing a small project with several files that need common imports, I think you'll be fine with `from module import *`, but it still would be **a better idea to refactor your code** so that different files need different imports.

So do it like this:

```
# something1.py
'''One of my project files. Takes care of main cycle.'''
import sys
....

# something2.py
'''Another project file. Main program logic.'''
import functools
from contextlib import contextmanager  # This is a long name, no chance to confuse it.
....
```

Comment: *Yes, just create a separate module and import it into yours.* It doesn't work for imports from `__future__`

Answer (score 7):

If you want default imports when using the python shell you can also set the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environmental variable to point to a python file that will be executed whenever you start the shell. Put all your default imports in this file.

Comment: Can you add an example about what each file should look like?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "each file": you simply use python `import` statements in the one file pointed to by the env variable.