# Python math module

Tags: python, math, module, import, logarithm

Whenever I try to use any of the built-in functions of Python's exponentiation and logarithms module, I get an error like this:

```
NameError: name 'sqrt' is not defined
```

I have tried using `math.sqrt(4)`,`sqrt(4)` and `sqrt(4.0)`, but none of them work. The exception is `pow`, which works as it's supposed to. This is really strange and I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: if the function is not a built-in, you have to import the module it is contained in. See [python library](http://docs.python.org/library/), and the [list of built-ins](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html).

Comment: I'm trying to imagine a scenario where you wouldn't want _math_ to be imported automatically on startup. [Python: Is there a place when I can put default imports for all my modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1350887/86967)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`pow` is built into the language(not part of the math library). The problem is that you haven't imported math.

Try this:

```
import math
math.sqrt(4)
```

Answer (score 18):

You can also import as

```
from math import *
```

Then you can use any mathematical function without prefixing math. e.g.

```
sqrt(4)
```

Comment: But be aware that the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) says: "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools.".

Comment: It can also "destroy" variables you defined elsewhere, e.g., if you had a constant or function "e" (e.g., for "error"), then `from math import *` will erase the definition with the constant e = 2.718281828 defined in the math module. Since you don't know all the names defined there, it's a bad idea. If you don't want to use "math." in front of each function, either import just what you need (`from math import sin,cos,exp,log`) or `import math as m` which allows you to use `m.sin`, `m.cos`, `m.exp`, `m.log`, ...

Answer (score 5):

add:

```
import math
```

at beginning. and then use:

```
math.sqrt(num)  # or any other function you deem neccessary
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to say `math.sqrt` when you use it.  Or, do `from math import sqrt`.

Hmm, I just read your question more thoroughly.... How are you importing `math`?  I just tried `import math` and then `math.sqrt` which worked perfectly.  Are you doing something like `import math as m`?  If so, then you have to prefix the function with `m` (or whatever name you used after `as`).

`pow` is working because there are two versions:  an always available version in `__builtin__`, and another version in `math`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math #imports math module

import math as m
print(m.sqrt(25))

from math import sqrt #imports a method from math module
print(sqrt(25))

from math import sqrt as s
print(s(25))

from math import *
print(sqrt(25))
```

Answer (score 0):

In

from math import sqrt

Using sqrt(4) works perfectly well. You need to only use math.sqrt(4) when you just use "import math".

Answer (score 0):

```py
import math as m
a=int(input("Enter the no"))
print(m.sqrt(a))

from math import sqrt
print(sqrt(25))

from math import sqrt as s
print(s(25))

from math import *
print(sqrt(25))
```

All works.

Comment: Dont put the code directly. Provide explanation. Go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to answer better