# Is there any way to import python modules for an entire package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package

I have a package structure that looks like this

```
├── Plugins
│   ├── Eight_Ball.py
│   ├── Ping.py
│   ├── Weather.py
│   ├── __init__.py
```

Every .py file inside the package needs to import a few modules from elsewhere in the project. I'd rather every file in the package didn't start with

```
from ..Utils.constants import Plugin_Type
from ..Models.Plugin import Plugin
from ..Models.Singleton import Singleton
```

so is there a way to have files in the `Plugins` package have those imports by default?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350887/python-is-there-a-place-when-i-can-put-default-imports-for-all-my-modules

Comment: There is not any acceptable way.  It's generally discouraged to hide dependencies.

Comment: @wim I already import `Plugin_Type` in `Plugin`. Would it be okay to 
`from ..Models.Plugin import Plugin, Plugin_Type`
 
`from ..Models.Singleton import Singleton`
instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Is there a place when I can put default imports for all my modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350887/python-is-there-a-place-when-i-can-put-default-imports-for-all-my-modules)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, no, there is no way to have files in the `Plugins` package import things by default.

Although it is generally discouraged to use `from module import *`, if you really wanted to save those few extra lines you could make a general import file that imports everything you need like this:

`common_imports.py:`

```
  from ..Utils.constants import Plugin_Type
  from ..Models.Plugin import Plugin
  from ..Models.Singleton import Singleton
```

`other_files.py:`

```
  from .common_imports import *
```

Again, using `from module import *` is discouraged, and I would recommend you simply include those few lines at the beginning of every file.